# Run program via command prompt as a user

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I've got a command prompt application on my phone, and whenever I run the `start` command it always runs the file as a system process, and the executable never visibly opens on the computer.

How can I do this? When I run command prompt on my computer itself, with the exact same command, it opens the window as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
runas /user:USERNAME program.exe
```

You will then be asked for a password for the user account.

**EDIT:** It appears that you are trying to run a GUI application, when you would need a RDP client for that, and not this remote command line program you seem to be using.

Comment: updated tags. The application hangs and never receives a "reply" from my computer...

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the app would still end up on a hidden private desktop, even if that desktop belongs to the correct user.

Comment: @Cyclone: If the username includes a space, put quotes around the whole of the /user switch and username.

Comment: @Joel: I am assuming that this is not actually a GUI application.  If it is, the OP should be using a RDP client instead of a remote command line.

Comment: @paranoid - could be, but he's looking for a window to appear.  I don't think he'll ever see one.

Comment: You know what happens when you assume...unfortunately I **am** looking for a window and this is a remote command line. There is a desktop application installed, which sends the results of commands back to the phone app. Why won't this work? Almost every other type of command works...